# Dynamically create OnClickListener in an array of EditText view(s)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I would like to create an array of EditText view(s), and then assign OnClickListener for only "Date-related" EditText view(s) inside the array. The Listener will pop-up a DatePickerDialog for user to input. Code as below:

```
oEditText = new EditText[oFieldNames.length];    // oFieldNames contains field names like e.g. "Student ID", "Student Name", "Birth Date", "Start Date", "Gender", etc. 

for (int i = 0; i < oFieldNames.length; i++) {
    oEditText[i] = new EditText(oContext);
    ...

    // code for "Date-related" EditText view:
        if (oFieldNames[i].toLowerCase().contains("date") == true) {
            oEditText[i].setFocusable(false);
            oEditText[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int day = oCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    int month = oCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int year = oCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(oContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay) {
                            oEditText[i] = (iYear + "/" + (iMonth+1) + "/" + iDay);
                        }
                    }, year, month, day);    // ERROR here!!!
                    datePickerDialog.show();    
                }
            });
        }
}
```

As expected, error message appeared complaining **variable 'i' is accessed within an inner class and must be declared "final"**. Well~ variable 'i' of coz should not be 'final' as I am doing a for-loop with 'i'. Looks like I need to restructure the code by creating a new custom EditText class, but its troublesome. Any idea on how to make small change(s) so that it can run successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here i have made some changes to make variable i to final . try it

```
for (int i = 0; i < oFieldNames.length; i++) {
    oEditText[i] = new EditText(oContext);
    ...

    // code for "Date-related" EditText view:
    if (oFieldNames[i].toLowerCase().contains("date") == true) {
        oEditText[i].setFocusable(false);
        final int tempI=i;
        oEditText[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int day = oCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = oCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = oCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(oContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay) {
                        oEditText[tempI] = (iYear + "/" + (iMonth+1) + "/" + iDay);
                    }
                }, year, month, day);    // ERROR here!!!
                datePickerDialog.show();    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @TsuiJohn please mark this answer correctly. May this will help others also

Answer (score 0):

Inside for loop Assign that i value into final variable then use it  like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < oFieldNames.length; i++) {
final int index = i;
oEditText[index].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("TAG", "The index is" + index);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a final EditText for each loop which references the EditText in the array.  
 Also inside `onDateSet()` use `setText()` to set the text of the EditText. 
Change your code to this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < oFieldNames.length; i++) {
        oEditText[i] = new EditText(oContext);
        final EditText et = oEditText[i];

        // code for "Date-related" EditText view:
        if (oFieldNames[i].toLowerCase().contains("date") == true) {
            et.setFocusable(false);
            et.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int day = oCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    int month = oCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int year = oCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(oContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay) {
                            et.setText(iYear + "/" + (iMonth+1) + "/" + iDay);
                        }
                    }, year, month, day);    // ERROR here!!!
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create final variable before invoke setOnClickListener and creating inner class.

```
final int j = i;
```

then use j instead of i